# Copy/move a list of files to a new directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I have an huge amount of files (e.g. 110011basz.dat, 110012basz.dat, 110013basz.dat,...) inside a folder, call `folder`. On the other hand I have a list related to the files I need to move to another folder (let´s call it `folder2`). This list doesn't show the full name of the files but just the prefix such as 110011.

Now how can I move those files into `folder2`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are all filenames with the pattern `number `+`basz.dat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list.txt` has names of files (with only prefix) one in each line, the following code will move all listed files to `folder2`:

```
while read file; do mv "$file"basz.dat /path/to/folder2; done < /path/to/list.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It´s seems that this code try to do something unfortunately I get the following error message "mv: cannot stat `11081\rbasz.dat': No such file or directory". Do you have any idea why? thank you!

Comment: Because your `list.txt` file has <CTRL>M<CTRL>J at the end of each line. Linux/UNIX uses a single <CTRL>J, and the `read` command sets `$file` to "11081<CTRL>M". <CTRL>M is also known as "\r" (backslash r).