# How to copy file from a list to a new folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, copy

I have a file *file1.txt* located in a *trial* folder containing the location of image files. I want to read the list, and copy the image files to a new folder, *test_folder*.

The entries in file1.txt look like:

```
./trial/data/image1.jpg
./trial/data/image2.jpg
```

etc.

I tried to use a similar question to solve the problem: [Copy/move a list of files to a new directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655051/copy-move-a-list-of-files-to-a-new-directory)

**Attempt**

```
while read file; do cp "$file" /trial/test_folder; done < /trial/file1.txt
```

I get the error "bash: /trial/file1.txt: No such file or directory". Any help would be great!

Comment: I have updated the question to include that - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are reading `/trial/file1.txt` and not `./trial/file1.txt`. That means the shell is trying to find a directory called `trial` which is under the root directory (`/`). If you want a path that is relative to your current directory, you can just use:

```
while read file; do cp "$file" trial/test_folder; done < trial/file1.txt
```

Or,

```
while read file; do cp "$file" ./trial/test_folder; done < ./trial/file1.txt
```

Or, you can use the full path:

```
while read file; do cp "$file" /home/shane/trial/test_folder; done < /home/shane/trial/file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. I am very new to Linux so that was a great help

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `xargs` and `cp --target-directory=...` thusly:

```
xargs -r <trial/file1.txt cp --target-directory=./trial/test_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but `rsync` is also a great way to do this:

```
rsync -av --include-from=trial/file1.txt --exclude="*" . ./trial/test_folder
```

- The source directory is the current directory, since the lines in `file1.txt` are relative to the current directory.
- The destination directory is the new folder.
- We exclude everything, except what matches the entries in the file