# Copy files from a list with spaces in the names to a new destination in Ubuntu

Tags: server, bash, cp

so i have an mp3 playlist (playlist.txt):

```
/home/ME/music/These guys/The first dumb track.mp3
/home/ME/music/Band two/my fav track04.mp3
/home/ME/music/Some other weirdos/The third One.mp3
```

obviously the list is way longer..

How do i make a batch file (bash?) That will copy all the files in this txt to a specific directory??

or is there a command i can run that will do this?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: See [How to copy file from a list to a new folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127773/how-to-copy-file-from-a-list-to-a-new-folder) - but note that if you use the answer based on xargs, you will need to set the delimiter to newline (`xargs -r -d '\n'`) to avoid splitting the arguments on whitespace.